# How to fix this AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My tensorflow version=2.0.0,keras version=2.1.5,python version=3.7

code:

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import argparse
import json
       
from PIL import Image
from mtcnn import MTCNN
detector = MTCNN()
```

return a error as like:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the newer versions of Tensorflow have inconsistencies.

Try either downgrading your tensorflow version `pip install tensorflow==1.13.1`

or upgrading your Keras to something 2.3 or above `pip install -U keras`

If you're brave you could also go digging to find which python file has a line like `import keras.something.something` and change it to `import tensorflow.keras.something`